# Ordering database resultset first by users, then by date

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table ("tweets"):

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| user_id | _date      | tweet_id |
+---------+------------+----------+
| 1       | 2011-03-17 | 12       |
| 1       | 2011-03-17 | 16       |
| 1       | 2011-01-18 | 17       |
| 2       | 2011-03-18 | 23       |
| 2       | 2011-01-17 | 29       |
| 2       | 2011-03-17 | 32       |
| 2       | 2011-01-17 | 33       |
| 2       | 2011-03-18 | 34       |
| 2       | 2011-01-19 | 45       |
| 2       | 2011-03-19 | 48       |
| 3       | 2011-01-19 | 50       |
| 3       | 2011-03-19 | 51       |
| 3       | 2011-01-19 | 52       |
| 3       | 2011-01-20 | 53       |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

I want the following output: tweets PER user ORDERED BY date:

```
user_id  _date       cnt
------------------------
1        2011-03-17  2
1        2011-03-18  1
2        2011-03-17  3
2        2011-03-18  2
2        2011-03-19  2
3        2011-03-19  3
3        2011-03-20  1
```

I don't understand why, but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT user_id, _date, COUNT(tweet_id) AS cnt FROM tweets 
GROUP BY nyse_date ORDER BY sp100_id ASC
```

Could someone explain to me why?

Comment: Where do the `nyse_date` and `sp100_id` columns come from?

Comment: Also I guess each time you wrote `2011-01-*` you meant `2011-03-*`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. Not sure why you have `nyse_date` and `sp100_id` in there? You need to group together `user_id` and `_date`, and order by them. This should do it for you:

```
SELECT user_id, _date, COUNT(tweet_id) AS cnt FROM tweets 
GROUP BY user_id, _date ORDER BY user_id, _date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT user_id, _date, count(*) AS cnt
FROM tweets
GROUP BY user_id, _date
ORDER BY _date ASC
```